# What is the use of Sharepoint site feature "Class Web Types"..?Please provide appropriate link or answer

Tags: sharepoint-online, feature, sharepoint-on-prem

I Want to know when we should use "Class Web Types" feature.What this feature does?Any help will be appreciated